# Get BLKID of an unmounted volume in go

Tags: unix, go

I am trying to find out if there is a way to get details of blkid of an unmounted volume, through some native golang library. I am particularly interested in fstype of the volume

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62759969/5291015) from [How to get the file system type programmatic for syscall.Mount()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62759448/5291015)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a native library - I couldn't find one.

I think you've got 3 choices

1. [Shell out](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) to the `blkid` utility
2. Write a [cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) interface to [libblkid](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.21/libblkid-docs/)
3. Trawl through the `libblkid` source and re-implement it in go

1 is very easy.  2 is harder.  3 might be easy depending on exactly which feature of `blkid` you want.  `strace blkid args` and seem how many system calls it does to get the result you want to get an idea.

I'd probably go with 1. as `blkid` is one of the core linux tools which you are guaranteed to have I think.

Comment: I went with 1 for now, I will explore 2 & 3 later. Thank you.