# How to get the file system type for syscall.Mount() programmatically

Tags: linux, bash, go, filesystems, mount

The function [Linux `syscall.Mount`](https://golang.org/src/syscall/syscall_linux.go?s=20289:20384#L786) requires a file system type.

If you try to run it with the file system `auto`, like this:

```golang
func main(){
    if err := syscall.Mount("/dev/sda1", "/mnt1", "auto", 0, "w"); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Mount(\"%s\", \"%s\", \"auto\", 0, \"rw\")\n","/dev/sda1","/mnt1")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

It will fail with `no such device`. It was already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35484096/2153777) that [Linux `syscall.Mount`](https://golang.org/src/syscall/syscall_linux.go?s=20289:20384#L786) just wraps `mount(2)`, [which doesn't itself support the concept of an "auto" fstype](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html).

I know how to find it using bash:

```golang
root@ubuntu:~/go/src# blkid /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: UUID="527c895c-864e-4f4c-8fba-460754181173" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="db5c2e63-01"
```

or

```
root@ubuntu:~/go/src# file -sL /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=527c895c-864e-4f4c-8fba-460754181173 (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)
```

In both cases you get the `ext4` file system type.

Replacing `auto` with `ext4` in Go will solve the problem, **but** what I am interested in is, how can I use Go to get the file system type of, for example, `/dev/sda1`?

Is there a function similar to `blkid` or `file` that can show the file system type of the device?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get BLKID of an unmounted volume in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324739/get-blkid-of-an-unmounted-volume-in-go)

Comment: Well, it was asked 5 years ago, I was hoping someone already did "Trawl through the libblkid source and re-implement it in go" so lets wait to see if someone know better way, I will check if I can re-implement it based on the source code.

Comment: Fair enough. I couldn't find anything through a quick search but if you do, please update the linked question with the information.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try using the [package blkid](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/LDCS/qslinux/blkid?tab=doc) ? It seems to work out of the box as it internally implements the `blkid` shell command underneath (see [blkid.go#L101](https://github.com/LDCS/qslinux/blob/master/blkid/blkid.go#L101)). You can just get the key name for the map returned from the `Blkid()` function and reuse it in your API

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    blkid "github.com/LDCS/qslinux/blkid"
)

func main() {
    rmap := blkid.Blkid(false)
    var key string
    var result *blkid.Blkiddata

    for key, result = range rmap {
        fmt.Printf("Devname: %q\n", key)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Uuid_=%q\n", result.Uuid_)
    fmt.Printf("Uuidsub_=%q\n", result.Uuidsub_)
    fmt.Printf("Type_=%q\n", result.Type_)
    fmt.Printf("Label_=%q\n", result.Label_)
    fmt.Printf("Parttype_=%q\n", result.Parttype_)
    fmt.Printf("Partuuid_=%q\n", result.Partuuid_)
    fmt.Printf("Partlabel_ =%q\n", result.Partlabel_)
}
```

The `Blkiddata` struct contains all the information as with the default Linux version

```
type Blkiddata struct {
    Devname_   string
    Uuid_      string
    Uuidsub_   string
    Type_      string
    Label_     string
    Parttype_  string
    Partuuid_  string
    Partlabel_ string
}
```

Just get the module using

```
go get github.com/LDCS/qslinux/blkid
```

It also implements the other family of Linux utils namely - `df`, `dmidecode`, `etcfstab`, `etchosts`, `etcservice`, `etcshadow`, `etcuser`, `hp`, `md`, `nmap`, `parted`, `scsi`, `smartctl` and `tgtd`. See [module github.com/LDCS/qslinux](http://github.com/LDCS/qslinux)

Comment: Yes it works, the only thing is that the Go BLKID is using the linux command `blkid` (https://github.com/LDCS/qslinux/blob/a234189e8187ce93e6e4e3cafba172925b0fa38a/blkid/blkid.go#L101) which I could use directly without this library. I will give it a chance to see if I can understand what is the "magic" that `blkid` is doing and if I won't find I will accept it as an answer. Thanks for the informative answer :)

Comment: @E235: Sure, if you can't use this, then you are left with doing point 2) of the linked question in the comments. Writing a `cgo` wrapper over `blkid` module

Comment: I will just mention that the original function of `blkid` can be found here:
https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/7c16238c069f171f376731c93435655be6df916b/libblkid/src/devname.c#L49-L146 and it is being called by this function: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/7586e9d1aa3d054efc0a4c959c41be98660072b0/misc-utils/blkid.c#L942