# syscall package does not have constants for filesystem type

Tags: linux, go, filesystems

I am looking for constants to compare with available filesystem types present in the system.
I can find out what filesystems are present in the system using mounts/df.

But my use case is to do a file search. And restrict my search to specific filesystem type when provide the type to macth with.

Please suggest some other ways to do it if you know.

I tried to look for constants in the syscall package but did not find anything.

chatGPT is also giving weird and obsolete APIs to find filesystem type.

Comment: I found the question that intents to find the same. Leaving it here... 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759448/how-to-get-the-file-system-type-for-syscall-mount-programmatically